# Disable sorting in datatables jquery plugin on specifc conditions

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am using datatables plugin for Jquery.I want to display records in descending order and it works fine.But when user clicks on header check box,I do not want to sort it again as it refreshes and unchecks all checkboxes.Here is my code

```
var oTable = $('#listings_row').dataTable( {
    "aaSorting": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
    "aoColumns": [ null, null],
    "sDom": 'R<>rt<ilp><"clear">',
    "iDisplayLength": 25,
    "iDisplayStart": 0,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "sAjaxSource": "test.php",
    "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
      var id = aData[0];
      $(nRow).attr("id",id);
  // Bold the grade for all 'A' grade browsers
  if ( aData[0] != 0 )
  {
  $('td:eq(0)', nRow).html( '<input type="checkbox" name="delid[]" value="'+ aData[0] +'" />' );
  } return nRow;
});
```

How to use `{ "bSortable": false }` with `aaSorting`?

Answer (score 0):

To disable sorting in a specific row on a table, just add the class `no-sort` to your `<th>` table definitions and add this code to the datatable initialization:

```
$('.dataTable').dataTable({

    // Disable sorting on the no-sort class
    "aoColumnDefs" : [ {
        "bSortable" : false,
        "aTargets" : [ "no-sort" ]
    } ]
});
```